# Missing implicit in Phantom Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra

Phantom 2.14.5

Scala 2.12.1

I'm experiencing: *could not find implicit value for parameter sg: com.outworkers.phantom.macros.SingleGeneric.Aux[User,Repr,HL,Out]*

when I try to implement an insert using the generated save. Here are my definitions.

```
case class User(
                 id: UUID,
                 email: String,
                 firstName: String,
                 lastName: String,
                 passwordHash: String,
                 createdAt: DateTime,
                 updatedAt: DateTime
               )

abstract class Users extends Table[Users, User] {

  object id extends UUIDColumn with PartitionKey
  object email extends StringColumn
  object first_name extends StringColumn
  object last_name extends StringColumn
  object password_hash extends StringColumn
  object created_at extends DateTimeColumn
  object updated_at extends DateTimeColumn

  def getById(id: UUID): Future[Option[User]] = {
    select.where(_.id eqs id).one()
  }

  def add(user: User): Future[UUID] = {
    store(user)
      .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.ALL)
      .future()
      .map(_ => user.id)
  }
}


class AppDatabase(override val connector: CassandraConnection)
  extends Database[AppDatabase](connector) {
  object users extends Users with Connector
}

object Database extends AppDatabase(connector)
```

Any insight is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: got the same error. Any progress?

Comment: Can't remember to be honest, I just decided to stick to postgres.

Comment: I got rid of the error by replacing store() with the tedious insert()... But I guess it defeats the purpose of having a store() method.

Comment: Try to move `getById` and `add` methods out of the `Users` class, into a `UsersService` trait or something.